# Check if plugin used "compile files" when it should've used "provided"

Tags: java, android, gradle, plugins, build.gradle

**Little background for context:**

The application I support allows third parties to develop plugins that can leverage some of our functionality. We hand them our "externalAPI.jar"; they put it in their project, implement some interfaces, and build their own APK. We find the would-be plugin by asking the package manager for all installed applications and see if each has a "pluginclass.xml" in the assets directory. If it has that XML file, we anticipate its contents being the canonical path of a class that implements our ExternalPluginVX interface, and using a `new PathClassLoader(ApplicationInfo.sourceDir, this.getClass().getClassLoader())`, we load the class, create a new instance, and start using it.

**The problem:**

Sometimes third parties will put

```
compile files ("./libs/externalAPI.jar")
```

in their gradle files instead of the correct syntax:

```
provided files ("./libs/externalAPI.jar")
```

The result of course being things don't work properly. Sometimes they almost work, but then have unpredictability in their behavior - usually involving vicious crashes. Notably, since their APK is well-formed in its own right, and the XML file is there, we'll see the plugin, load the target class successfully, instantiate it successfully, and things go haywire from there when they try and reference back to us.

**The question:**

Is there a way for my application to check at runtime if the other application compiled our API classes into their APK instead of using `provided files` like they should have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A viable solution is to use a `DexFile`.

Since I already have the `ApplicationInfo.sourceDir`, I can just construct a `DexFile` and iterate through its contents.

```
//this variable's value assigned by iterating through context.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0)
ApplicationInfo pkg; 

String interfaceTheyShouldntHave = ExternalPluginVX.class.getCanonicalName(); //"com.project.external.ExternalPluginVX"
DexFile dexFile = new DexFile(pkg.sourceDir);
Enumeration<String> entries = dexFile.entries();
while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
    String entry = entries.nextElement();
    if(entry.equals(interfaceTheyShouldntHave)){
        Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Plugin \"" + pluginName + "\" could not be loaded. Please use 'provided files' instead of 'compile files'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
}
```